# Standing barionic waves in CMB require that the geometry - i.e. the spatial perimeter condition - does not change for a sufficiently long time

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, bao

Standing barionic waves in CMB require that the geometry - i.e. the spatial perimeter condition - does not change for a sufficiently long time. How long should the standing wave of a byryon oscillation be sustained to not be significantly affected by cosmological spatial expansion, and at the same time to provide the measurable effect of today's measurements.

Comment: Baryon acoustic oscillations are not associated with standing waves. They are related to the distance sound can travel in the early universe, i.e. to traveling waves.

Comment: I have a similar view, but I have come across multiple claims that these are standing acoustic waves and have had trouble understanding this.